# Motherboard and RAM speed compatibility

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I have this motherboard: https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/X299%20Taichi/index.asp#Specification

And 8 16G Kingston RAM: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-Technology-HyperX-HX430C15PB3K2-16/dp/B01GCWQ6AM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1517849118&sr=8-1&keywords=kingston%2Bpredator%2Bddr4%2B3000%2B16gb&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GCWQ6AM)

The motherboard states the supported memories are:

> - Quad Channel DDR4 Memory Technology
> - 8 x DDR4 DIMM Slots
> - Supports DDR4 4400+(OC)* / 4266(OC) / 4133(OC) / 4000(OC) / 3866(OC) / 3800(OC) / 3733(OC) / 3600(OC) / 3200(OC) / 2933(OC) / 2800(OC) /
>     2666 / 2400 / 2133 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
> - Supports non-ECC RDIMM (Registered DIMM)
> - Max. capacity of system memory: 128GB**
> - Supports Intel® Extreme Memory Profile (XMP) 2.0
> - 15μ Gold Contact in DIMM Slots

Note that there is no DDR4 3000MHz in the supported list. But my memory is of that speed(I've already bought them). Can I still use these memories with my motherboard?

Comment: I went ahead and answered this question but due to the fact, you failed to look at the ASRock's memory QVL before submitting this question, I am going to downvote it.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually I've checked the list but I'm not quite understand what it is. Thank you for the answer and I'll learn more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I still use these memories with my motherboard?

Yes; The `Kingston Technology HyperX Predator Black 32GB Kit`is 100% compatible with your motherboard.

[image]

- [Memory QVL (SKL-X)](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/X299%20Taichi/index.asp#MemorySKL)
- [HX430C15PB3K2/32](https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX430C15PB3K2_32.pdf)